# System of differential equations of second order $X''(t) = -(A^2)X(t)$

Tags: differential

How do I solve problems of the form
$$X''(t) = -(A^2)X(t),$$
where $X$ is a $2 \times 1$ matrix and $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix?  We're given $X(0)$ and $X'(0)$.

Comment: Is $A$ a constant?

Comment: This is an initial value problem. Where A is a square matrix.

Comment: With $B=-A^2$, the solution is $$X(t)=C(t)X(0)-S(t)X'(0)$$ with $$C(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{t^{2k}}{(2k)!}B^k\qquad S(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{t^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}B^k.$$

Comment: @Did Why not $X(t) = e^{iAt}$? Because $X'(t) = iAe^{iAt}$ so $X''(t) = (iA)^2e^{iAt} = -A^2X(t)$.

Comment: @JohnMartin Perhaps because 1. the solution would not depend on $X(0)$ and $X'(0)$, 2. the solution would take imaginary not real values while $X(t)$ is real valued if $X(0)$ and $X'(0)$ are, 4. the solution you suggest might correspond to the initial conditions $X(0)=I$ and $X'(0)=iA$.

Comment: *Correction: $X(t)=C(t)X(0)+S(t)X'(0)$.